# i don't get fetch data from firebase real time database to angular 6

Tags: angular, firebase

i'm using angular 6, "@angular/fire": "^5.1.1", "firebase": "^5.6.0", i want to fetch all data of my database, but don't get it, i tried of a lot of ways, this is my appmodule.ts:

```
          import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
      import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
      import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
      import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
      import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

      import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


      @NgModule({
        declarations: [
          AppComponent,

        ],
        imports: [
          BrowserModule,
          AngularFireDatabaseModule,
          AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        ],
        providers: [],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
      })
      export class AppModule { }
```

...and this is my appcomponent:

```
      import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
      import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
      //import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
      import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

      @Component({
        selector: 'app-root',
        templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
      })
      export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


        courses: Observable<any[]>;

          constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase){
              this.courses=db.list('/courses').snapshotChanges();
          }

            getData(){
              return this.courses;
            }

          ngOnInit(){
              console.log(this.getData());
              debugger;
          }
      }
```

....i also tried with:

```
this.courses=db.list('/courses').valueChanges();
```

...and

```
this.courses=db.list('/courses').subscribe(courses=>{
                this.courses=courses;
              });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the docs:

**valueChanges():** `The current state of your collection. Returns an Observable of data as a synchronized array of JSON objects. All Snapshot metadata is stripped and just the method provides only the data.`

You should subscribe to the Observable returned from the function, so:

```
courses: Observable<CourseModel[]> | Observable<any> | any;
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase){
  this.courses=db.list('/courses').valueChanges()
    .subscribe(courses => {
      console.log(courses); // Check the returned values;
      this.courses = courses;
    })
}
```

Comment: ...and how can i to declare this.courses: observable, array, or what?

Comment: You can set the type for your object like `course: Observable<Course>`, where Course is an interface or a class. But you dont need to do it, you can simply declare `courses: any;` I'll update the answer.

Comment: i tried with a test proyect  that i created and this work perfectly, but could does have a problem when i have a lot of data?, i have a database with a sensor that send register each 2 minutes and in this moment there are a lot of data, this code doesn't work, on the  browser console appear  Array(0)

Comment: Well, I've used Firestore and I know that it's not that good for querying documents. I don't think you want all the registers, maybe only an aggregation that gives you information instead of only data, if it's your case I think you should take a look in another noSql database like elasticSearch or mongoDB, they ares better doing complex queries. But if you need to get each value, you could try to pass a limit and an offset using the `collection.get()` method. Good lucky!

Answer (score 1):

`snapshotChanges` return an observable. We need to subscribe to the observable to get the data.

```
 constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase){
      db.list('/courses').snapshotChanges().subscribe((response) => {
             this.courses= response;
      });
 }
```

Comment: ...and how can i to declare this.courses: observable, array, or what?

Comment: this.courses should have a same type as response data. declare it in the class level like `course: you_data_type[] = []`